# How to implement a regex that detects javascript comments into php

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex (https://regex101.com/r/3a9OKx/1) that fully (I hope) detects javascript comments. The regex seems to detect `//` and `/* ... */` as well as ignoring those in quotes and the problems around `.replace(/'/...` - which is all good.

[image]

But I'm not sure how to put this into php to remove those detected items.
I've tried using a preg_replace_callback (https://onlinephp.io/c/2d3e9) but I don't seem to get the result I want

```
$html=<<<'PATTERN'
doSomething('aaaaa//cccccccc'); // c1ccccccc
/* c2cc' cc'ccc */
doSomething2(111, 222, 333); // c3ccccccc
abc.replace(/'/g, 'aaaaaa//aaaaa'); /* c4ccccccc */
abc.replace(/"/g, 'aaaaaaa'); /* c5ccccccc */
doSomething("<div>aaaaaaaa//aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</div>",1234);// c6ccccccc
doSomething('<div>aaaaaaaa//aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</div>',1234);// c7ccccccc
PATTERN;

$regex=<<<'PATTERN2'
~((["'])(?:\\[\s\S]|.)*?\2|(?:[^\w\s]|^)\s*\/(?![*\/])(?:\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)\]|.)*?\/(?=[gmiy]{0,4}\s*(?![*\/])(?:\W|$)))|\/\/.*?$|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/~
PATTERN2;

$newJS = preg_replace_callback($regex
            , function ($m) {
                if ( strcmp(substr($m[0], 0, 2), "/*")==0 ) return "xx";
                if ( strcmp(substr($m[0], 0, 2), "//")==0 ) return "xx";
                return $m[0];
            }, $js);
```

resulting in

```
doSomething('aaaaa//cccccccc'); // c1ccccccc
xx
doSomething2(111, 222, 333); // c3ccccccc
abc.replace(/'/g, 'aaaaaa//aaaaa'); xx
abc.replace(/"/g, 'aaaaaaa'); xx
doSomething("<div>aaaaaaaa//aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</div>",1234);// c6ccccccc
doSomething('<div>aaaaaaaa//aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa</div>',1234);xx
```

So how do I do this?

Comment: Throw away regexps and implement a parser. RE just not gonna work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: regex is not the right tool for this.  For instance, it does not recognise JavaScript template literals, which have their own particularities (e.g. multiline, used with `String.raw`, ...).

But to your immediate issue: the difference between your regex101 and PHP attempts is that the second lacks the multiline pattern modifier, which means the `^` and `$` anchors are interpreted differently.

Fix it by appending `m` at the end of the regex:

```
$regex=<<<'PATTERN2'
~((["'])(?:\\[\s\S]|.)*?\2|(?:[^\w\s]|^)\s*\/(?![*\/])(?:\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)\]|.)*?\/(?=[gmiy]{0,4}\s*(?![*\/])(?:\W|$)))|\/\/.*?$|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/~m
PATTERN2;
```

## Improvements

A sequence of `// abc // def` is wrongly matched as if `/ abc /` is a regular expression literal, missing the point that it is a comment. To fix this, change `[^\w\s]` to `[^\w\s\/]`

The look ahead assertion `(?=[gmiy]{0,4}\s*(?![*\/])(?:\W|$))` is too strict, which will reject a valid regex closure, looking further for a good closure leading to potential catastrophic backtracking. For instance, this regex is fine: `/abc/du` yet the regex would spend lots of time to find a different ending for this regex. Anyway, when a regex literal has a non-escaped forward slash, it should be taken as the ending delimiter. The flags that follow are not really interesting to assert, since they don't pose a risk to be interpreted as a comment by another pattern. So just drop that look ahead:

```
$regex=<<<'PATTERN2'
~((["'])(?:\\[\s\S]|.)*?\2|(?:[^\w\s\/]|^)\s*\/(?![*\/])(?:\\.|\[(?:\\.|.)\]|.)*?\/)|\/\/.*?$|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/~m
PATTERN2;
```

Comment: Thanks Trincot - that worked. I hear you on the not the right tool - but what would you use instead?

Comment: Best practice is to use a bullet-proof parser that produces an Abstract Syntax Tree. To be honstest, I didn't find one that is available to PHP in a brief search... In JavaScript there is Esprima.

Comment: I did spot php_strip_whitespace but it doesn't seem to handle javascript perfectly (I've been able to catch it out with `.replace(/'/g,`). Real shame as it's so close to being the solution (with the performance) that's needed as the definitive comment stripper for javascript (something that's been asked so many times on stack - but I've not found one perfect solution yet).

Comment: In a JavaScript environment the solution is to use something like Esprima. But to do it in PHP on JavaScript source code, that's a combination I haven't found.

Comment: Was there a problem with the answer I provided?

Comment: It did - but when I ran the pattern against a much larger test via PHP I get an empty string returned, and a preg_last_error = 2 from preg_replace_callback (The number of backtracks needed to evaluate the expression exceeded the limit given in PHP's configuration)) - so I'm still investigating how to resolve that. (it also fails with additional slashes in // comments).

Comment: Can you link to the large test case?

Comment: For the additional slashes in comments, you need to alter the regex: change `[^\w\s]` to `[^\w\s\/]`. Added to answer.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/1KBaYS/1 for the larger test case

Comment: The pattern for finding the end of a regex literal is causing this catastrophic backtracking. The lookahead should be removed as it will reject valid regex-endings, and it serves no good purpose otherwise. See update of answer.

Comment: BTW, that large example is not valid JavaScript. For instance this statement is invalid: `gPRtaEqSvj _PwqDNOHOfDrZfdWAbpUAZi = 382780;/*CSnYfUGSnGSk*/` and `/,/xi` is a regex with an invalid flag.

Comment: That improvement did the trick. (The example was an obfuscation of the real code - but should have been sufficient for the regex problem). Thanks again for your help.